# css3 image transition in unorderedlist - to top

Tags: css, css-transitions

i want to use an unordered list to display some icons in a row..

on mouseover (hover) the icons should get bigger, which already works fine but the icons grow to the bottom.. what i need is: the icons should grow to the top.  i guess this is a position problem: can someone help with a sample css?

html and css:

```
    <div id="container">

<ul>
    <li><img src="test.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="test.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="test.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="test.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="test.jpg" /></li>
</ul>


</div> <!-- end of #container -->


<pre>

          ul {
    position: absolute;
  }

li {  
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
  }

  ul li {
  float: left;
  }


  ul li img:hover {
    width: 142px;
    height: 142px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;  
  }

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a transform - scale instead, with a transform origin set at 100% of y position